# localNotification issues

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, uilocalnotification

I am sending a local notification once a process is finished and it acts just fine.

This is my code for didReceiveLocalNotification:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{

    CounterViewController *counterVC = [CounterViewController sharedInstance];
    [counterVC notificationArrived];
}
```

But when the iPhone is locked those lines aren't called… What can I do to make them run in the background?

Answer (score 1):

There are two method to receive local notification one is already you have implemented which is invoked while app is running & 2nd is in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions which is invoked while your app is running background you have add some code for receive local notification .....

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Add the view controller's view to the window and display.


application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

// Handle launching from a notification
UILocalNotification *localNotif =
[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
if (localNotif) {
    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",localNotif);
}

return YES;
```

}